# Waiting x seconds before continuing while continuing to respond to user input and render frames

Tags: .net, xna, lua, wait, luainterface

### Background

I am currently creating an XNA application that utilizes [LuaInterface](http://luaforge.net/projects/luainterface/) so that I can control the application with [Lua scripts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_%28programming_language%29).

---

### What I Want

I've noticed that a lot of things will probably be 'time' based in my development.  Such things may include *showing information and then removing it after x amount of seconds*, *end a game in defeat if it takes x amount of seconds*, or even used in *easing a camera a certain distance every x seconds*.  I wanted to implement the `wait` function in Lua as opposed to my application, but at this point, I'm open to input (because I can't seem to get it to work).

---

### What I've Tried So Far

***inv.lua***

```
 _G.Wait=(function(t)
    local dest=Time.ElapsedMilliseconds+t*1000
    while Time.ElapsedMilliseconds<dest do
        gel:UIUpdate()
    end
    return true
 end)

 --Aliases
 _G.wait=Wait
```

***gELua.vb***

```
Public Sub UIUpdate()
    Application.DoEvents()
    Game.Tick()
End Sub
```

(Where `Game` is My XNA Game Object)

---

### So Why Doesn't My Idea Work?

The current problem is that, even though I'm calling `Game.Tick()` every time to keep everything going, the XNA part of my application stops receiving input.

---

So, my question is, is there a better way to do this?  I thought it was working pretty well until I encountered the problem with user input.  Have any of you implemented something like this that worked well?

Comment: Will the entire script "wait" for the time specified? For example is "toast.lua" a separate script from, say "someentity.lua" ?

Comment: It does wait correctly, even from other scripts because I added the function to the global table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is for your game loop to continue running - but not call "Update" (that's inside a lua script) for an object. If each of your objects are different scripts, then this is fairly simple. A "Wait(*time*)" method will only tell your game engine that "this" object doesn't want to be updated for *time* milliseconds. The engine will note that down and continue calling Update and Render for all the other scripts (objects).

The next time it comes around to Update/Render the "waiting" object, it will skip the "Update" call and call only Render instead. When the timeout expires - you can resume calling Update on the object. If possible - you could resume execution of the Update method from the next line you suspended it from. This would make writing the script simple, like a C# "async" method.

Of course - this depends heavily on how your scripts interact with the rest of your engine. If the described solution does not work for you, I would request you to describe how your scripts interact with the engine in greater detail.